# cgo - "undefined reference" error when linking dynamic library in GO

Tags: go, linker-errors, cgo

I have a C++ shared library in `/opt/xx/lib64`. Headers are in C.
In my go code, I am including proper header and linker options using CPPFLAGS/CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. Still while building go I am getting 'undefined reference` error.

```
import (
    //#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/opt/xxx/lib64/ -lsessionmgmt
    //#cgo CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/xxx/include/
    //#include <stdlib.h>
    //#include <sessionMgmt/sessionMgmt.h>
    "C"
    "unsafe"
)
```

```
/tmp/go-build609413262/b163/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_e38947506e9d_Cfunc_um_get_lastlogin_info':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:52: undefined reference to `um_get_lastlogin_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:48: vet] Error 2
```

Library is exist in the right path and do contain the required method.
Not sure why this error.

`$ grep um_get_lastlogin_info /opt/xxx/lib64/libsessionmgmt.so
Binary file /opt/xxx/lib64/libsessionmgmt.so matches`

Also tried using the `pkg-config` with cgo. Still the same linking error appears.

Comment: This question is specific to "CGO" and I feel this is not related to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Finally go community helped to identify the problem. There was extern "C" missing in my header. after re building the library, linking issue is solved.  More details [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31723)